# What is the intersection of $o$,$θ$ i.e $o \cap θ =$?

Tags: functions, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

Is there anything common in between small oh and theta ?

i.e. If we consider a function $f(n)$, then what is the intersection of all the set of functions for which $f(n$) is the upper bound and the set of functions which are asymptotically equivalent to $f(n)$ ?

This seems to be null, but I'm not sure if that is true. And if possible, can you also point out the results of possible combinations of $o,O,ω,Ω,θ$ in same way ?

Comment: Regarding the definitions: $f = O(g)$ means $|f|$ is bounded by $M g$ for some $M$. $f = o(g)$ is a stronger claim, it means $|f|$ is bounded by $M g$ with any positive $M$. $f = \Theta(g)$ means that $f$ and $g$ are big O's of one another (but not necessarily asymptotically equivalent).